# RethinkDB: Not able to insert into table using select which includes joins (basically insert into select..)

Tags: insert, rethinkdb

I have tried the following code:

```
r.db("videojet").table("testdm").insert(
  r.db("videojet")
    .table("data_value")
    .getAll("687D2CD7-4B0A-4EE4-A4F6-2F67C0CDA449", {index: "printerid"})
    .innerJoin(
      r.db("videojet").table("model_msg_data").getAll("65605151",{index: "modelmsgdataid"}),
      function (datavalue, modelmsg) {
        return datavalue("modelmsgdataid").eq(modelmsg("modelmsgdataid"));
      }
    )
    .map({
      printerid: r.row("left")("printerid"),
      modelmsgdataid: r.row("left")("modelmsgdataid"),
      datetimestamp: r.row("left")("datetimestamp"), 
      datatagname: r.row("right")("datatagname")
    })
    .innerJoin(
      r.db("videojet").table("printer"),
      function (datavalue,printer) {
        return datavalue("printerid").eq(printer("printerid"));
      }
    )
    .map({
      printerid: r.row("left")("printerid"),
      modelmsgdataid: r.row("left")("modelmsgdataid"),
      datetimestamp: r.row("left")("datetimestamp"),
      datatagname: r.row("left")("datatagname"),
      modelid: r.row("right")("modelid"),
      serialnumber: r.row("right")("serialnumber")
    })
    .innerJoin(
      r.db("videojet").table("model"),
      function (datavalue,model) {
        return datavalue("modelid").eq(model("modelid"));
      }
    )
    .map({
      printerid: r.row("left")("printerid"),
      modelmsgdataid: r.row("left")("modelmsgdataid"),
      datetimestamp: r.row("left")("datetimestamp"),
      datatagname: r.row("left")("datatagname"),
      modelid: r.row("left")("modelid"),
      serialnumber: r.row("left")("serialnumber"),
      modelname: r.row("right")("modelname")
    })
 )
```

and when I run it in the console it appears to be doing something.  I'll check the dashboard and I can see the Reads go up.  Eventually the reads go to 0, the query is still hanging and nothing seems to happen.  BTW.  The query (or should I say the select) is limited to 81 rows of data, if I ran without the insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

There query you posted is very complicated. The fact that you're nothing happens might be related to a lot of different things. Rather than try to provide a solution, I'll try to help you **debug** your query.

**Is the issue in the insert or in the query inside the insert?**

What is the results of the main sub-query inside your insert? It seems to me that that query probably results in some empty array or object which is the reason why it's not getting inserted.

I would also try to going through the query per parts:

1. What is the result of this?

Code:

```
r.db("videojet")
  .table("data_value")
  .getAll("687D2CD7-4B0A-4EE4-A4F6-2F67C0CDA449", {index: "printerid"})
```

2. What happens when you add the innerJoins? Does it stop at any of the `innerJoin`s?
3. Does the result work if you split the insert and the `getAll`, save the results of `getAll` to a variable and then pass it to insert?

You might find the [`zip`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/zip/) command pretty useful, since it might save you from some of the `map` statements.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this Jorge.  I have tried many different variations of this.  I was able to get this to work when I used zip and only had one innerjoin.  When I added the 3rd one it just hung, and the same happened with the 4th (as seen above).  I did use the .zip() function and .map() when I got it to work.  It is just really weird that it doesn't work when I add more joins.  To be clear, If I run the statement above and take the insert out it will return data.  I have decided that Rethink probably isn't the right DB for what I am trying to do.  thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not just do an `innerJoin` then save the result to a variable (do any checks) and THEN do the insert. Wouldn't that work? Just curious.

Comment: Also, what database do you normally use/think might be better for this? SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Jorge - I ended up using Postgres, and although saving the results and inserting them would have worked, I was looking for something scalable that could be done easily and without manual intervention.  Although rethink probably could have solved the problem, I didn't feel comfortable since the DB is so new and there isn't a lot of documentation available.  Again, thank you for your time.